# Android Management API Kiosk Mode No Notification Sound

Tags: android, android-intent, mdm, kiosk-mode, android-management-api

Working with Android Management API that has a custom launcher app set to Kiosk mode. In this way it overrides the old launcher.

However, it does not receive notifications from for example whatsapp and Gmail because of the Kiosk mode in Android Management API.

Is there a way to bypass this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue on android 8.1 and below with  no fix available on those versions. This should not be an issue on later versions.. To enable notifications you should add `"statusBar": "NOTIFICATIONS_AND_SYSTEM_INFO_ENABLED"` in your (`KioskCustomization`)[https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#kioskcustomization] policy.

Comment: After adding in: "kioskCustomization": {
    "statusBar": "NOTIFICATIONS_AND_SYSTEM_INFO_ENABLED"}, in such a way and having:   "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "launcherpackage",
      "installType": "KIOSK",
      "autoUpdateMode": "AUTO_UPDATE_HIGH_PRIORITY"
    },

It still does not work, and wont allow me to receive notifications

Comment: @rsiasion Any idea how to fix this issue?